# Void inside c++ struct doesn't change one struct value

Tags: c++, function, struct, pass-by-reference

I have this struct

```
typedef struct _flight {

    FlightId flightId;

    int totalPlaces;
    int booked;

    float currentPrice;
    float initialPrice;

    void Print(int index);
    void RecalculatePrice();
    bool BookSeats(int amount);
} Flight;
```

And that is causing troubles, BookSeats:

```
bool Flight::BookSeats(int cantidad) {
   if (booked + cantidad <= totalPlaces) {
      booked = booked + cantidad;
      RecalculatePrice();
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

When I call BookSeats the value change isn't stored at end of method (like when you pass one variable by value into the arguments), I tried to use

```
this->booked = booked + cantidad; // but doesn't work too;
```

What I'm doing wrong? I don't know if is a reference problem but... variable and void are both inside the struct. I don't understand.

Comment: sure that the condition is satsfied?

Comment: and it would be better if you show as a complete example ?

Comment: What does the constructor for `Flight` look like?

Comment: Please provide more details abt how you are using this code

Comment: Hi guys, more info, it's a bigger application from flight managing, from school where we use a subset of c++. I can't build the struct, only declare and set to {0}: In this app i use it from an flightarray (`f_array[choice-1].BookSeats(amount);`) thats the code i use, thank you for all the answers. @HumamHelfawi, yes, the condition satifies (the flight at init has 0 booked ;) ).

Comment: For your info, we dont have sizeof() function then i can't use malloc() for start a pointer (is a pain in the a*s).

Comment: @DrkDeveloper [`sizeof` isn't a function it's an operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Comment: Textbook example of why we require a MCVE. And if you haven't composed one yet, then you haven't finished your debugging yet.

Comment: If you "don't have `sizeof`" then something is seriously wrong, you are not actually writing C++, and this is all pointless.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, MCVE ok, but the variable names are in spanish, it is a problem? sizeof absence i dont not why but the "learning language" (subset c++) doesn't have it or not allow it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here is it http://1drv.ms/1TjhJN5 (7z file, its checked it works) sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No, not a 7z file linked from off-site in the comments. A MCVE, in the question.

Comment: Solved guys! thanks for your help. The problem was the app generates duplicated flight (in the array setup). Then the changed flight wasn't the stored in the main storage. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Before use variable you need to initialize it by setting a value. 
If your compiler accept c++11 you can do it directly inside a class/struct, like this:

```
struct Flight {
    int booked = 0; // in-class initialization (c++11)
};
```

For older c++ compilers constructor of Flight should be initialize its members:

```
struct Flight {
    Flight() : booked(0) {}
    int booked; 
};
```

Comment: As you can read in the comments up, i dont 'build' the struct, i declared and set to zero with C style. `Flight f = {0}`

Comment: @DrkDeveloper: Instead of hiding that information in the comments, produce a full example of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Then people like alex won't be wasting their time taking random guesses at what your code does.